# Highlight Multiple Search Terms In Order Given

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Have seen simple `preg_replace` (or even just `str_replace`) examples of adding `<span class="highlight">` around an array of searched words. But a lot of search queries will search for terms in the order written:

Search: `blue shoes`

MySQL query: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE title LIKE '%blue%shoes%'`

Matches:

`MATCH` - "Don't step on my `blue` suede `shoes`"

`NO MATCH` - "... his fancy shoes and his baby blues..." (the keywords are not in the right order)

`MATCH` - "`blue` `shoes` under the blue sky" (second "blue" should not be highlighted)

`MATCH` - "... the `blue` notebook... her `shoes` and threw the blue, plastic horseshoe..."

So the SERP should highlight the matches the same way. Is there a REGEX way that will accomplish this with *n* search terms in order? Or does this need to be handled with a PHP loop somehow?

### Incorrect Attempt:

```php
foreach ( ['blue', 'shoes'] as $term ) {
    $result = str_replace($term, "<span style=\"background:yellow\">$term</span>", $title);
}
echo $result;
// This will highlight any instances of "blue" or "shoes" in any order in the result,
// even though the MySQL query searched for those terms in that specific order
```

Comment: Simply construct fixed regex based on search terms like: `(blue).+(shoes)`

Comment: Thanks @CodeSpirit, but looking for how to output this given `n` search terms.

Comment: It seems you are addressing the symptom and not the actual problem. Do you _want_ the search term order to matter? It shouldn't.

Comment: Hey @AlexHowansky, yep, I definitely want the query to function that way. Since this is the way a lot of search functions work (say for looking for symbols in a large project) I crafted the query intentionally. But the way many examples of keyword highlighting function, ALL keywords are highlighted in any order... the database will make sure we're getting the correct results, but the highlighting doesn't properly represent what was searched for. Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using `implode()` for building the search pattern and `preg_replace()` for doing the actual replacing:

```
$haystacks = [
    "Don't step on my blue suede shoes",
    "... his fancy shoes and his baby blues...",
    "blue shoes under the blue sky",
];
$needles = ['blue', 'shoes'];
$format = '<span style="background:red">%s</span>';

function highlightMatches($needles, $haystack, $format)
{
    $search = '('.implode(')(.+?)(', $needles).')';
    $replace = '';
    $gaps_count = count($needles) - 1;
    foreach ($needles as $k => $needle) {
        $replace .= sprintf($format, '\\'.($k * 2 + 1));
        if ($k < $gaps_count) {
            $replace .= '\\'.($k *2 + 2);
        }
    }

    return preg_replace("/$search/", $replace, $haystack);
}


foreach ($haystacks as $haystack) {
    echo highlightMatches($needles, $haystack, $format)."<br>";
}
```

If the database query is available for editing, I'd try to use the database query to do the highlighting.

Comment: Oh, interesting idea. How would you use the database query itself to do the highlighting? Lemme play with this.

Comment: Okay, yes, this is they was I was imagining doing it... just dynamically building up a regex pattern and replace. Was thinking there may have been a simpler `preg` option I was missing. I'll throw this on my SERP and see what all passes.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned [mysql], so I present what probably comes quite close to your request in finding the row in question.

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST(+"blue shoes" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If your question is only about PHP code, then remove the [mysql] tag.

Comment: Oh I've never seen the `MATCH AGAINST` pattern. I'll have to play with that some time. META: I would think the tags should reference relevant concepts within the question, not necessarily the language in which the answer is expected. The tags also serve to attract interest from people who follow them, so for example, my question would be best served by users who follow those specific tags. I dunno, that's just how I read the guidelines.

Comment: Ahh, match against is awesome. I can match multiple columns at once. Looks like the columns must be FULLTEXT indexed. This is definitely useful to me in the future. Though your query will return `blue...shoes` as well as `shoes...blue`, not enforcing the order. Thanks Rick!

Comment: @PhilTune - Another note:  When indexing multiple columns, the  `MATCH` list must match the `FULLTEXT` list.  Eg, `MATCH(a,b)` and `FULLTEXT(a,b)`; simply `(a)` in either place won't with `(a,b)` in the other.  It is OK to have two indexes (`(a,b)` and `(a)`) if you need both types of `MATCH`.

Comment: There are cases where `MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AND ... LIKE ...` is useful -- the `LIKE` is to refine the results of the `MATCH`.  The combo is reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the regexp pattern with PHP:

```
function highlightMatches(array $searchTerms, string $string): string {
    $result = $string;

    foreach ($searchTerms as $i => $term) {
        $previous = array_map(function($item) {
            return "($item)";
        }, array_slice($searchTerms, 0, $i + 1));
        
        $pattern = implode(".+", $previous);
        
        $matches = [];
        preg_match("/$pattern/", $string, $matches);
        
        $lastMatch = array_pop($matches);
        
        if ($lastMatch) {
            $result = str_replace($lastMatch, "<span style=\"color: red;\">$lastMatch</span>", $result);
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}


$searchTerms = ["first", "second", "third"];

$strings = [
    "first second third",
    "third second first",
    "second third first",
    "third first second",
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo $str . ":\t" . highlightMatches($searchTerms, $str) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So this highlights the second, third and fourth strings, but those don't match the query `...LIKE '%first%second%third%'`. This query requires all three keywords in that order. (of course the query itself won't even include those in the serp, but the expected result is highlighting only the parts of the string that would have caused the database row to match.)